# How to manage service workers in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

In Mozila, we can view service workers by `about:serviceworkers`.
Is there any option in chrome to manage/delete service workers?

I have a worker in google chrome background displaying unwanted browser push notifications?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [Application tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage) of Chrome's DevTools provides has "Service Worker" panel, and using that, you can manually uninstall unwanted ones. (By default it will only show service workers that are currently in scope, but if you check the "Show all" box, you'll see all of them.)

Older versions of Chrome only supported `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, which is still around and can be used for the same purpose, but you'll probably find the DevTools interface friendlier.